# porque de una etiqueta <a> con ruta "ruta/{{$var}}/edit" y un 'action': "ruta/{{$var}} mi ruta final es: ""ruta/{{$var}}/"ruta/{{$var}}"?

Tags: php, html, laravel, url

Tengo una vista en Laravel con el siguiente código:

```
<h1>Edicion</h1>
@foreach ($usuarios as $usu)
  <h4>{{$usu->nombre}}</h4>
  <a href="prurequests/{{$usu->slug}}/edit">editar</a>
@endforeach
```

Un controlador:

```
Route::resource('/prurequests','PruebasControllers\PrurequestsController');
```

Con método edit:

```
public function edit($slug)
{
  $usuario = Usuario2::where('slug','=',$slug)->firstOrFail();
  return view('vistaspruebas.edit', compact('usuario'));
}
```

Cuando llego a esta vista mi URL es:
[/public/prurequests/vaca/edit](http:///public/prurequests/vaca/edit)

en esta vista tengo este codigo

```
<form action="prurequests/suma method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
  <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
  <br />
  <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>
</form>
```

y Laravel en vez de buscar esa ruta: **"prurequests/suma "** busca esta **/public/prurequests/vaca/prurequests/suma**

¿alguien sabe porque después de esa etiqueta  y de llamar a otra ruta me quita el 'edit' y lo cambia por la ruta que sea que ponga ?

Comment: que te devuelve esto $usu?

Comment: Es un ejemplo una variable en este caso un nombre. @x-rw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar los helpers de laravel:

```
<form action="{{url('prurequests/suma')}}" method="POST">
   @method('PUT')
   @csrf
   <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
   <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
   <br />
   <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta la comilla despues de suma en la accion del formulario y adicionar los helpers

```
<form action="prurequests/suma method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
  <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
  <br />
  <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>
</form>
```

Deberia quedarte :

```
<form action="{{url('prurequests/suma')}}" method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
  <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
  <br />
  <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>
</form>
```

o bien pudieras hacer tu formulario de esta forma:

```
Route::post('prurequests/suma', 'PrurequestsController@suma')->name('prurequests.suma');

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'prurequests.suma']) !!}

    <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
    <br />
    <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```